# How to delete the first 10 row from database SQlite in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am building an android application where I am using data helper class to store the data.

Now the problem I am facing is How can I delete top old 10 data from table.

I am using below query but my application crashed.

```
    public void deleteRec() {
    String ALTER_TBL ="delete from " + TBL_NAME +
            " order by _id LIMIT 3);";
    db.execSQL(ALTER_TBL);
    }
```

And calling using -

```
new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext()).deleteRec();
```

Comment: Have you tried to take away the last ")" ?

Comment: After remove bracket, change the 3 to 10 ;)

Comment: I updated my answer once check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once try as follows

```
String ALTER_TBL ="delete from " + TBL_NAME + " where rowid IN (Select rowid from " + TBL_NAME + " limit 10)";
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

DELETE with LIMIT is not enabled in the SQLite library used in Android.

You have to use a subquery to get the IDs:

```java
String ALTER_TBL = "delete from " + TBL_NAME + " where _id in " +
        "(select _id from " + TBL_NAME + " order by _id limit 10)";
```

Comment: I guess this is the real reason it didn't work. Beside the ')' that shouldn't be in the query. DELETE with LIMIT has to be enabled with compile options, see: https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the last parentheses:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I too think that this is the problem can you  please suggest me better way to do that

Comment: Remove that and try again.If it gives errors, copy it and add it to your question

Comment: What I should remove ?

Comment: you have to remove the bracket

Comment: @hiteshmatnani remove the perenthesis `)`.